# Finding how many features inside drawn Polygon using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#

I have drawn a polygon. Using SpatialFilter I found and processed all the features in it. But I wanted to get the feature count before working with the features.

Is there any method that I can use to determine that the count of features in a drawn Polygon Geometry beforehand?

I have drawn a polygon. The intersecting features inside the Polygon. Also, I wanted myself to count of all the features inside that drawn boundary. For example, if 1 transmedia and 1 structure are there in the drawn boundary. I am supposed to have the feature count 2. I am anyhow getting the count at the time of processing. But I have to find the count before hand. Why I am doing it beforehand since I want to find what is the percentage of processing done at a certain time and display it in progress bar.

Here is a snippet.

```
while ((esriLayer = esriEnumLayer.Next()) != null)
                {
                    if (esriLayer.Valid) // Checking if the layer is a valid layer
                    {
                        esriFeatureLayer = esriLayer as IFeatureLayer;

                        IFeatureCursor esriFeatureCursor = esriFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.Search(spatialFilter, true);


                        if (esriFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.ShapeType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        while ((esriFeature = esriFeatureCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
                        {
                            int count = 0;
                            totalNumberOfFeatures++;
                            _progressStatus = 5;
                            string message = "Validating " + esriFeature.Class.AliasName.ToString() + ":" +                 esriFeature.OID.ToString();
                            ShowProgressBar(_progressStatus, message);

                            lstFeature.Add(esriFeature.Class.AliasName.ToString());

                            esriInvalidFeature = ReadConfigAndValidateFeature(esriFeature, message);
                            _progressStatus = _progressStatus + 60;
                            ShowProgressBar(_progressStatus, message);
                            if ( esriInvalidFeature != null )
                            {
                                string Key = esriInvalidFeature.Class.AliasName.ToString() + ":" +                                  esriInvalidFeature.OID.ToString();
                                if (!diction.ContainsKey(Key))
                                {
                                    diction.Add(Key, esriInvalidFeature);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                             }
                          }
                        }
                     }
```

I am processing the features using the method # ReadConfigAndValidateFeature 
I am hardcoding the stuff for now. But I want to showcase the percentage.

Update : After seeing the useful hint I have written a full method to count the features. Here is the code #

```
private int FeatureCount(IMap mapInstance, ISpatialFilter spatialFilter)
        {
            int featureCount = 0;

            IEnumLayer esriEnumLayer = mapInstance.get_Layers(null, true);

            ILayer esriLayer = null;

            IFeatureLayer esriFeatureLayer = null;

            while ((esriLayer = esriEnumLayer.Next()) != null)
            {
                esriFeatureLayer = (IFeatureLayer) esriLayer;
                if (esriFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.ShapeType == 
                 esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (esriLayer.Valid) // Checking if the layer is a valid layer
                {
                    if ( 
                  esriFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.FeatureCount(spatialFilter) > 0)
                    {
                        featureCount += 
                      esriFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.FeatureCount(spatialFilter);
                    }

                }
            }
            return featureCount;
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to count feature of another shapefile inside your drwan polygon? This part is not cleare.

Comment: Update: I am trying to clear things up. I have drawn a polygon. The intersecting features inside the Polygon I need. Also, I need the count of all the features inside that drawn boundary. For example, if 1 transmedia and 1 structure are there in the drawn boundary. I need to have the feature count 2. I am anyhow getting the count at the time of processing. But I need the count before hand. Why I need it beforehand since I need to find what is the percentage of processing done at a certain time and display it in progress bar.

Comment: I have updated the code even. I think now I can make it clear.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: Hello Vince, I am sorry for writing the word "need" . I tried to remove that. You are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `IFeatureClass.FeatureCount()` method. It's [right here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IFeatureClass_FeatureCount.htm) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Berend for Adding your valuable comments and showed me the path for solution. But for this I am not getting the feature count directly. I was thinking that there might be some ESRI spatial function to count the features as we do count(*) in a Oracle. But it is working with little time. I am updating with the full code after seeing your comment.